# Is there a way to create a postgresql composite type in Sea-orm?

Tags: postgresql, rust, sea-orm

I am trying to replicate

```
CREATE TYPE name AS
    ( [ attribute_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [, ... ] ] )
```

in Sea-orm.

I am able to recreate an enum type `CREATE TYPE name AS ENUM` using

```
            DbBackend::Postgres => {
                manager
                    .create_type(
                        Type::create()
                            .as_enum(SomeTable::Table)
                            .values([SomeTable::Value, SomeTable::AnotherValue])
                            .to_owned(),
                    )
                    .await?;
```

but I have not been successful in replicating a composite type.